# save values of an element selected in array

Tags: jquery

I want to save selected items to an array.

for example:

```
 var list = $('ul.theList li'),
           result = $('div#result'); // other div
           content;

 for( var i=0; i < list.length; i++ ){
       content[i] = $('ul.theList li')[i];
 }

 $(result).text(content); // the result
```

This doesnt work.

Comment: `content=[]` you are missing the initialisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues, first you've not defined the `content` as an array, and with that code you should probably define how the array-elements should be joined:

```
 var list = $('ul.theList li'),
           result = $('div#result'),
           content = [];

 for( var i=0; i < list.length; i++ ){
       content.push($('ul.theList li:eq(' + i + ')').text());
       /* or:
       content.push($('ul.theList li').eq(i).text());
       */
 }

 $(result).text(content.join(', '));
```

[JS Fiddle demo using `:eq()` selector](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TekzQ/).

[JS Fiddle demo using `.eq()` method](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TekzQ/1/).

I've used `.push()` to insert the text of the `li` (I'm assuming, here, that you *want* the text and not the node itself) to the `content` array, rather than explicitly defining the index.

References:

- [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).
- [`.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Answer (score 1):

Better use jQuery now you have it

version 1

```
var list = $('ul.theList li'),

$('#result').text(list.text());
```

version 2

```
var list = $('ul.theList li');
list.each(function(i) {
  $('#result').append(i+".: "+$(this).text()+"<br/>");
});
```

Comment: So why not accept mine? I did not bother post the eq(i) because it was not necessary.